# how can I transform a list of objects into one string using java?

Tags: java, string, transform, iterable

I have a List which I want to transform to one string.

I wanted to use Iterables.concat or Iterables.transform

but non of them did what I wanted.

How can i do this in java?

Comment: I assume the `List` contains `String`s?

Comment: no, but that object has toString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to other answers, you can also iterate through the list and use a StringBuilder object to create and output a string for you, if you'd like control over what goes inbetween list entries.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    builder.append(list.get(i));
    builder.append("whatever you want inbetween");
}
String output = builder.toString();
```

Note that append will work for any primitive and will call the toString representation of any object you put in as a parameter, as per the java API.

Comment: You should have list.get(i).toString() if you want to output text. It is not guaranteed that his List contains String objects.

Comment: String builder can append any primitive. It calls the toString representation of object's automatically.

Comment: But what if his list isn't a number? It could be a list of Object or a list of Items or anything that he has built himself.

Comment: append will call the toString representation of any object automatically. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html Go down to the description of the append(Object obj) method

Comment: I stand corrected... you are absolutely right. I just learned something new today. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I didn't know either until I looked at the docs to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other perfectly valid answers in Java 8 you have `String.join(delimeter, iterable)` available to use.

Answer (score 2):

If the default `List#toString` method does not do what you want, you can get more flexibility with the Streams API:

```
String result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

In this form you can use whatever delimiter you want. If your list does not already contain strings, but the elements' default `toString` representation is good, then use

```
list.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(", "));
```

If you want custom logic for the conversion to string, just replace the mapping function, for example:

```
points.stream().map(p -> "(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")").collect(joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe simply `list.toString()` will do what you want.

Comment: But if you use your own classes in that list, you need to implement `toString()`  method.

Comment: You will have to do that for all of the solutions

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringUtils from Apache Commons Lang :

```
StringUtils.join(yourList, ',');
```

Edit : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Iterator